# Putting a image inside a input box

Tags: css

Similar to [Put icon inside input element in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form)

But how to I get the icon inside and on the *right side* of the box?

Comment: There is a closed question, pretty similar to this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634868/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form-not-as-background-image?lq=1

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
background: url(images/icon.png) no-repeat right center;
```

The explanation for this CSS is as follows:

background: [url to image] [don't repeat] [horizontal position] [vertical position]

Answer (score 8):

As an addition to [Bazzz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7062417/3100128), if you don't want the icon right up against the right border, you can specify padding on the right side.

```
background: url(images/icon.png) no-repeat right 10px center;
```

This will put the icon on the right side, but keep it 10 pixels from the very edge. So, the CSS explanation would look like this:

background: [URL to icon] [specify no repeating] [horizontal position] [padding on right side] [vertical position]

Answer (score 3):

Same answer except change `padding-left` to `padding-right`, and change the positioning of the background.

Something like:

```
background: url(images/comment-author.gif) no-repeat scroll right;
padding-right: 30px;
```

Comment: Have you tried using padding-right? I copied your example but for some reason the gif will always stay top-right and vertically-centered.

Comment: just figured out if you use background-position: right 30px top 10px positioning works well

Answer (score 2):

Using image and SVG. Padding works well in all browsers (mars 2017)

[image]

Image file

```
.date_element {
    background-image: url(../img/calendar.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    background-origin: content-box;
}
```

SVG file

```
.date_element {
    background-image: url(../img/calendar.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    background-origin: content-box;
    background-size: 2.5rem 2.5rem;
}
```