# Put icon inside input element in a form (not as background image!)

Tags: html, css, forms, input, icons

I want to do exactly what was asked here:

[Put icon inside input element in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form)

Except that I want the icons to be right-aligned.

The "background" workaround won't work, since those images have to be clickable! So it must be an IMG.

How can I do this?

Comment: Create a wrapper div for input and image, give relative position to the wrapper div and absolute position to the image

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A solution without background-images:

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2pbtB/573/)

```css
#input_container { 
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#input { 
    height:20px;
    margin:0;
    padding-left:30px;
}
#input_img {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:8px;
    left:10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="input_container">
    <input type="text" id="input" value>
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CornerStone/PNG/arrow%20right.png" id="input_img">
</div>
```

Comment: Added left padding to the input of your example so you could not type over the image -> http://jsfiddle.net/2pbtB/1/

Comment: `padding-left` works on I.E 8, but as soon as I type a long input, it shifts left and types over the image !

Comment: Thanks a lot,, it saved my time...

Answer (score 7):

You can use a div as a wrapper, containing an image and input field, and position the image inside there that overlay's the input field using position absolute.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://static4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131121214007/destinypedia/images/7/71/Information_Icon.svg" alt="">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    height:30px;
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
}

img {
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:5px;
}

input {
    width:100%;
}
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/aTvvN/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just try following:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" />
<img src='http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png' />
```

**CSS:**

```
input {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-right:none;
    float: left;
}
input:focus {
    outline:none;
}
img {
    float: left;
    height: 18px;
    width: 19px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left: none;
    margin: 2px 0px 0px -2px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pyx4k/)