# CSS: Set Inline element inside padding

Tags: html, css, frontend, instagram

I am looking at the Instagram website. I notice that they put a zoom icon inside the padding of adjacent input. I wonder how this is done, can somebody show me an example

[image: icon inside padding]

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put icon inside input element in a form (not as background image!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634868/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form-not-as-background-image)

Comment: since you already opened console why not just took at how they did it? from what i saw they used position absolute to place it there

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example for `jQuery` search box on focus show hide icon as per your reference. I hope this answer will be helpful.

```js
$('.btn-close').hide();
$('.fa-search').show();
$('.input-text').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.btn-close').show();
    $(this).siblings('.fa-search').hide();
});
$('.btn-close').click(function(e) {
    $('.fa-search').show();
    $('.btn-close').hide();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.input-text').on('focusout', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.btn-close').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.fa-search').show();
});
```

```css
.input-text {
    border: 1px solid #888;
    min-height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0 25px 0 5px;
}

.input-box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.input-box .fas,
.btn-close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    padding: 11px 4px;
    top: 0;
    color: #888;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-box">
    <input type="text" class="input-text" placeholder="text">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    <a class="btn-close" href="#"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that they don't actually put the icon inside the input box. The just draw a rectangle around both the icon and the `<input>`. The icon itself is added to the `<span>` on the line right after the highlighted `<input>` in the image in the question. Look for the class `coreSpriteSearchIcon`.

When I inspected that `<span>`, I saw these styles applied:

```
background-image: 
  url(/static/bundles/metro/sprite_core_2x_6ba81dcece9b.png/6ba81dcece9b.png);
}

background-size: 410px 396px;
background-position: -240px -366px;

height: 10px;
width: 10px;
```

The `background-image` is the sprite file (an image containing multiple smaller images). `background-size` ensure that the image isn't stretched. `background-position` tells you where to find the search icon within the larger sprite image. And, `width` and `height` tell you how much of the image to display.

They were able to place it where it is by using `absolute` positioning:

```
left: 11px;
position: absolute;
top: 9px;
z-index: 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to achieve this is to use `position: absolute` and put input into a wrapper. Let me show you:

```css
.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.input-wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}

input {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  
  font-size: 20px;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/30"/>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

So basically we use `position: relative` to move img relatively to it. Also note, that you have to add extra `padding`(left one in this case) so text won't overlap with icon.

There are a lot of ways to do the same: `position: relative`, negative `margin`, `background-image`, utilising of pseudo-elements, but absolute positioning is the most semantically correct in my opinion.