# float a icon over a text box without using position absolute

Tags: html, css

Ive been looking on the internet and could not find any solution to this.
It has to be possible.
I have a login area. There is a text box with a padlock icon at the start of the text box.
No this works using `position:absolute;`, but then you have to deal with browser positioning differences. Is there a way to float the icon over the tex box without using `position:absolute;`?

```
<div class="login_password_box">
    <i class="icon-lock"></i>
    <input type="password" id="login_password" value="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could set the icon as background for the input element. And then position it with background-position.

Have a look at this: [Put icon inside input element in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form)

---

```
#login_password {
    background: url('path/to/image.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WZ7jj/

Comment: a left padding applied would make it nicer ofc

Comment: I was using 'Font-Awesome', but i think I will revert to this solution. Thanks Luc