# Align search icon inside of input field?

Tags: html, css

How can I align a search icon within an input field (floating in the center on the right side)? I looked around and found some stuff about using it as a background image, not sure how to do this though.

```css
.search {
 border: #cccccc solid;
 border-width:2px;
 padding:9px;
 font-size:24pt;
 border-radius:10px;
 margin:0; 
 padding-left:30px;
 height:54px
}
.search:focus {
 outline:none;
}
#search {
 position:relative; 
 padding:0; 
 margin:0;
}
#srch_icon {
 height:32px;
 width:32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="search">
 <input type='text' class='search left'>
 <img src="search.png" id="srch_icon">
</div>
```

Comment: `width:32pxl` is that a typo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Put icon inside input element in a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form)

Comment: Unlike that I want it on the right side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a background image for sure:

```
#search input {
    background-image: url('search.png');
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can position an image with CSS using only background property.

```
background: color position/size repeat origin clip attachment image|initial|inherit;
```

in your case:

```
background: url(search.png) right center no-repeat;
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/arglab/dgy79e8y/1/

---

By the way, I think this will look better: http://jsfiddle.net/arglab/dgy79e8y/

Answer (score 0):

You can put a background image here is a example  http://jsfiddle.net/29qoevve/  `background: white url(...`