# jquery make CSS background-image inside a input fadeOut

Tags: jquery

I would like my `background-image` **Property** fadeOut after 3 seconds it is possible?

what I am trying to do is: make the image inside  that input do a fadeOut:

jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/930yrzqa

Comment: Read up on `setTimeout`

Comment: like that? : function bkgFadeOut(){
   $("input").css('background-image').fadeOut();
}
setTimeout(function(){bkgFadeOut();}, 2000); getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).css(...).fadeOut is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attemt to run fadeout function on css variable - this is not posible. This function is only for elements like div or img.

I guest, that you want to show the check icon on input and then hide it. The best way to do this is to add this image not as background but just as image then execute fadeOut on that img.

Here you can find an example:
[Put icon inside input element in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form)

example of timeout:

```
function explode(){
  alert("Boom!");
}
setTimeout(explode, 2000);
```