# How to place image correctly in input tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a input tag with two images cross and arrow.

Here is my code.

```
<div id="chart_line" style="position: relative;">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" list="myUL" onclick="openingList()" onkeyup="openingList()" style="width:30%;">
        <div id="triggers">
            <img class="trigger" onclick="deleteValue()" src="css/clearT.png" id="cross">
            <img class="trigger" src="css/combo_arrow.png" onclick="openingList()" id="arrow">
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is my fiddle :

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arsenal/j2ncjxj7/)

I am facing two problem here.

1. I want my image should be at the end with respect to input tag. Right now I am giving manually in CSS. You can see

   #triggers {
         position: absolute;
         left : 110px;
         top: 5px;
       }

I am giving `left : 110px` How can I fix this always at end of input tag. Input tag width may change.

2. I want to restrict my input tag just before the image start. Right now text is coming below the image. Even cursor is also going below the image. Any idea how to fix that.

Here is image for your reference.
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is this:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}
```

What used to be `#container` is now `#chart_line`, so if you change the above CSS to this:

```
#chart_line {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}
```

That should do something.

The next job is to change every `width: 30%;` in your code to `width: 30vw;`.

Then you need to give `#myInput` some padding:

```
  padding: 0 55px 0 7px;
```

Now all you need to do is remove the CSS `left: 110px` from `#triggers` and replace it with `right: 6px;`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#myInput {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #95B8E7;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 55px 0 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
#chart_line {
  position: relative;
  width: 30vw;
}
#textfield {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.trigger {
  width: 20px;
}
#triggers {
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart_line">
  <input type="text" id="myInput" list="myUL" onclick="openingList()" onkeyup="openingList()" style="width:30vw;">
  <div id="triggers">
    <img class="trigger" onclick="deleteValue()" src="css/clearT.png" id="cross">
    <img class="trigger" src="css/combo_arrow.png" onclick="openingList()" id="arrow">
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/AquatuzMagnus/pen/bRKLNe)

Comment: My DivID is dynamic, so Can I write css of div ID in this case #ChartLine dynamically or in Javascript

Comment: Do you mean inline styles? Such as: `<div style="position: relative; width: 30vw;"></div>` because if so, then that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.field {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
.field input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.field .triggers {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" value="some very long value to check what goes under the images">
  <div class="triggers">
    <img class="trigger trigger--cross" src="css/clearT.png">
    <img class="trigger trigger--arrow" src="css/combo_arrow.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please  explain what are you doing so It easy for me

Comment: @David : Putting a position 'relative' on the main div makes it possible to let the triggers div be positioned 'absolute'. By defining a 'right' value of '5px' it will always stick to the right of the main div. Hope this helps a bit. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a trick here. You need to put both the `input` and `imgs` inside a `div` then remove the border and properly style the components to make it look natural.

Here is a reference on how to do it.
[Put icon inside input element in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form)

Comment: Actually I tried the same, But I have two images so background image trick is not gonaa work.

Comment: It is possible, you just need to properly style it to accommodate numerous images.

Comment: let me give a try

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position:relative` to your parent div and to `input` and `triggers` add `position:absolute`.

Then add `width: 100%` to your input to take all the place of parent div and add `right: 5px` to your triggers to place them to the right.

And at the end add some `padding` to your `input` to avoid that text goes onder the `trigger` images.

Thus, something like this :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#chart_line {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}

#myInput {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #95B8E7;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

#triggers {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart_line">
  <input type="text" id="myInput" list="myUL" onclick="openingList()" onkeyup="openingList()" />
  <div id="triggers">
    <img onclick="deleteValue()" src="css/clearT.png" id="cross">
    <img src="css/combo_arrow.png" onclick="openingList()" id="arrow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here can you play with it. [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/j2ncjxj7/3/)