# Add child html to Django Form Input?

Tags: html, django

Currently I have a form in my web app rendering as (with classes and names removed for simplicity):

```
{% for field in form %}
  <div>
    {{ form }}
    <img src="{{ field.field.img }}">
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

field.field.img is just a path to the required image. This then becomes:

```
<div>
  <input ... />
  <img src="#">
</div>
```

What I would like to have is for it to be:

```
<div>
  <input ...>
    <img src="#">
  </input>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can have the image be a child of the input, rather than being placed alongside it?

Comment: That is *not* the way to include an image in an `<input>` box, this is the way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/917673/67579