# I need to place a non-editable (non-removeble) "%" sign in grey color in input right after text

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, addition, sign

http://jsfiddle.net/c6f7ommh/1 - Saw the example with div containers, but want to know if its possible to resolve with input

```
 $(document).ready (function() {
    var minNumber = 0;
    var maxNumber = 100;

       $('.txtinput').on("change", function() {
        var inputVal = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(' %', ' ')) || 0
        if (minNumber > inputVal) {
          inputVal = 0;
        } else if (maxNumber < inputVal) {
          inputVal = 100;
        }
        $(this).val(inputVal + ' %'); 
      }); 
      });
```

That is what I've made for now, but I'm very new to programming, so if you can provide some tips on how to complete it, would be awsome!

Comment: You might want to tag this question with whatever language this refers to.  What "example with divs" (whatever that means) are you referring to!?  In what way does it not work?  i.e. For a specified input what output do you expect, and what did you get instead?

Comment: Added more description, thanks @Clifford

Comment: do you want the input field's width to stretch while typing ? Or an input with fixed width alongside with a `%`  would suffice ?

Comment: The width of the input is fixed, only the "%" should move regardingly

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50997861/5530965) makes use of Bootstrap 4 but I believe it's similar to what you want? Also the answer makes use of icons but you can easily replace it with your `%` as a plain text.

Comment: [Here's another example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_form_icon.asp) that doesn't use Bootstrap. Again, it uses icons but you could tweak it to use plain text.