# How to highlight the prepend Font Awesome icon in Bootstrap 4 or Bootstrap-vue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am having something like this:

[image]

How do I expand the width that the border it will also cover the icon on the left like this:

[image]

My HTML:

```css
.input-group-text {
  width: 48px;
  border-right: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
[class^="fa-"], [class*=" fa-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.LoginInput {
  border-left: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<b-input-group>
  <b-input-group-prepend>
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i></span>
  </b-input-group-prepend>
  <b-form-input class="LoginInput" size="lg" placeholder="Username">
  </b-form-input>
</b-input-group>

<b-input-group>
  <b-input-group-prepend>
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg"></i></span>
  </b-input-group-prepend>
    <b-form-input class="LoginInput" size="lg" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    </b-form-input>
</b-input-group>
```

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form)?

Comment: I tried the padding left but it doesn't work, it moves the text area to the right and add the padding

Answer (score 0):

I found [this working demo](https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/aBnbL) by James Barnett. He uses font awesome icons with css to implement position: absolute; on the icon and text indent to implement what you are trying to achieve. He places the icon and the input field inside a container div.

HTML

```
<div class="search">
  <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
  <input placeholder="Search term">
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-    awesome.min.css");
  body { margin: 30px; }

.search {
  position: relative;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 16px;
 }

.search input {
  width: 250px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc, 0 10px 15px #ebebeb inset;
}

.search input { text-indent: 32px;}
.search .fa-search { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

Find the full thread [here.](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-do-i-put-icons-inside-of-input-fields)

I hope this is of some help.

Comment: I could position the icon easily, but when in focus mode the icon just disapear.

Comment: My suggestion would be to follow the code as per the example without focus, as that does everything you want it to and can be adapted to use the icons you want