# How to render fontawesome as button in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a button with `fontawesome` icon using the below snippet:

```
<div className="form-group  col-md-2">
   <input type="button" className="btn btn-default">
   <i className="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> add
   </input>
</div>
```

But I keep getting this error:

> input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: <input /> does not closed with </input> .. add the icon with css

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate more ?

Comment: add the icon as background-image .. and position it 
Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React, `<input />` cannot render any child elements. Instead, use `button`.

```
<div className="form-group col-md-2">
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-default">
        <i className="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> add
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is an example in [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-button-with-icon-example-r7yob).

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states with `input` element unfortunately you could not have any element inside.

One possible solution can be to use `button` instead of `input` element. By adding a `CSS` class and set the `content` property as in the below example, read from the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp):

> The content property is used with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, to insert generated content.

```css
.icon-content:after {
  content: ' add';
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-default icon-content" />
```

Hope this helps!