# Style a particular text in input field

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible at allto style only a particular text of an input field.Like SO's tag input field

Assuming, I have an input field `<input value="some text"/>`, is it possible to style only the text 'some' but not 'text'?

If not, what are some alternatives?

Comment: on what basis you are going to define which text need style ? or this will be like start word need style ?

Comment: Is there any logic, what is the pattern you want to achieve? like even words get style or what ?

Comment: @ROOT how did you understand what he wants? I mean I can give that answers too, but what OP needs actually that is unclear. Just style the `some`. will this be same everytime?

Comment: @DupinderSingh, you are right, I removed my answer anyway, I took a closer look at the question, I didn't read it well before, this is just as as simple as using [select2](https://select2.org/tagging#tagging-with-multi-value-select-boxes)

Comment: @Out of the box Please read this document and try again with a clear Question https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61924566/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do it inside `<textarea>`. A workaround is to create a "fake" textarea using a `<div contenteditable>`. Then you can use something like:

```
let input = document.querySelector(".input");


input.innerHTML = input.innerHTML.replace("some", `<span class="hl">some</span>`);
```

and apply CSS to the span class:

```
.hl {
  color:red;
}
```

[More on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible as the style is applied to the entire content of the input field.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121683/is-there-a-way-to-style-part-of-an-input-fields-value) someone suggested a tricky "solution" to simulate the behaviour, but it's far from being something recommended or built-in.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it with an `input`, since the `value` of an `input` is not an element in the DOM you can access or style. You would likely need to use a `contenteditable` element. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content).

Comment: Good thought, but it's actually a `textarea`. That's why you can't see any of the markdown or other formatting inline, but see it in a separate preview block instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this just using the  tag, but there are some workarounds:

[Span inside text input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499163/span-inside-text-input-field/6499257)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a regular `<input type="text">` or `<textarea>` element, but with a normal element (like `<div>` or `<p>`) made `contenteditable`, you have all the freedoms of html/css formatting.

```
<div contenteditable>
    ST<span style="color: red">A</span>CK OVERFLOW
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jVqDJ/

The browser support is very good as well (IE5.5+). Read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable