# how can i display content in editable text area?

Tags: php, html, css

please i want to display content in editable text area but is not possible it only display input text

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputAddress2">News Bar</label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control"  name="title" id="inputAddress2" value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>" placeholder="Enter your news bar"
```

Comment: Do you have some code of your editable textarea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form This could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is as example putting icons in the field. You can use any other elements you wish by following the same principal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        .input-icons i {
            position: absolute;
        }
         
        .input-icons {
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
         
        .icon {
            padding: 10px;
            min-width: 40px;
        }
         
        .input-field {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
 
<body>
    <h3>
      Icons inside the input element
  </h3>
    <div style="max-width:400px;margin:auto">
        <div class="input-icons">
            <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
            <input class="input-field" type="text">
            <i class="fa fa-instagram icon"></i>
            <input class="input-field" type="text">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
            <input class="input-field" type="text">
            <i class="fa fa-youtube icon"></i>
            <input class="input-field" type="text">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook icon"></i>
            <input class="input-field" type="text">
        </div>
  </div>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the help, but the problem is on the edit form, if i click on the edit button the edit form dont show information of the textarea