# How can I make an search form like this?

Tags: html, css, search

I just wonder is here is any easy way to make search button like this:[There is a search form I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3kVj.png)

For now I have smth like this:[This is what I have for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6zLl.png)
And there is HTML and CSS:

```css
.path1{
    max-width: 18px;
    max-height: 18px;
}
.search-button{
    border-bottom: #0A093D;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="search-button">
        <form id="form"> 
          <button><img class="path1" src="C:\Users\przem\Projekty\strona-task\img\1024px-Search_Icon.svg.png"></img></button>
          <input type="search" id="query" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Put icon inside input element in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go...

```css
input {
  border: none;
}

.search-button {
  width: 250px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-button">
  <form id="form">
    <button><img class="path1" src="C:\Users\przem\Projekty\strona-task\img\1024px-Search_Icon.svg.png"></button>
    <input type="search" id="query" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this help me a lot. Now Im not stuck in place

Answer (score 0):

you can also put a unicode inside the placeholder.

```css
.path1{
    max-width: 18px;
    max-height: 18px;
}
.search-button{
    border-bottom: #0A093D;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-button">
        <form id="form"> 
          <input type="search" id="query" name="q" placeholder="  ︎   Search...">
        </form>
      </div>
```