# CSS expanding Search Bar, how to add icon to end?

Tags: css, input

I'm using a CSS expanding search bar and when the bar is open I want to add an 'x' icon to the right hand side within the input.

The bar I'm using is here:
https://codepen.io/Tom_T/pen/YzgaYNv

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #111;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    background-color: #444;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 32px;
    padding-right: 32px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.button:hover {
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

.search-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.mglass {
    display: inline-block;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.searchbutton {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.search:focus + .searchbutton {
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

.search {
    position: absolute;
    left: 49px; /* Button width-1px (Not 50px/100% because that will sometimes show a 1px line between the search box and button) */
    background-color: white;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.search:focus {
    width: 363px; /* Bar width+1px */
    padding: 0 16px 0 0;
}

.expandright {
    left: auto;
    right: 49px; /* Button width-1px */
}

.expandright:focus {
    padding: 0 0 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container">
    <input class="search" id="searchleft" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search">
  
    <label class="button searchbutton" for="searchleft"><span class="mglass">&#9906;</span></label>
</div>
```

I've tried adding the following after the input and the moving it with CSS, but it always shows and is before the search icon.

`<img src='x.jpx' class='clear' />`

How would I add an icon to the right handset when it's expanded ?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form You need to put it as background image in the input element.

Comment: Adding it as a background images doesn't allow it to be clickable.

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.